# Regenrate proxy in each curl request

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I have added a Proxy in my `CURL` by using

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, trim($proxy));
```

And my Proxy is like

```
$proxy = '105.9.59.90:4450';
```

This `CURL` is executing in my `CRON job`. When my system hits a number of requests by using this Proxy the system block this Proxy. Now, i want to make this Proxy dynamic so that due to number of hits the proxy will not blocked. 
In simple words, is there any way to generate dynamic Proxy on each `CURL` call?

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple proxy IPs you can just pick one at random:

```
$proxies = array(
  '105.9.59.90:4450',
  '105.9.59.91:4450',
  '105.9.59.92:4450',
  '105.9.59.93:4450',
  '105.9.59.94:4450',
  '105.9.59.95:4450'
);

$proxy = $proxies[array_rand($proxies)];
```